# How to remove package uninstaller notification (in notification bar)?

Tags: uninstallation, 8.0-oreo

I installed tower fortress game from playstore and after when I uninstalled it this notification sticked in my notification bar and is not going away!
It's been more than 4-5 hours and still it's sticked there!

Experts plz help me!
My phone:- Lenovo K8 Note Android Oreo

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the device, if it does not go away force stop the "Package installer" service from `"Settings > Apps"`

Comment: When I go to settings, app and search for the package installer it's not there. Is there any other way to get it off!? It's been days and I can't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Notification Bar and Long press on notification.
Then click on information button and block package installer notification and then enable it .